# java google app engine query from string (like Python's GQL)

Tags: java, google-app-engine

```
    final DatastoreService dss = DatastoreServiceFactory
            .getDatastoreService();
    Query query = new Query("GQL query goes here!");

    /*
     * Like this GQL query:
     * 
        q = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM People "
            "WHERE first_name = John "
            "AND last_name = Smith")
     */
     */
```

Is there any way to make it possible?
The thing is, I want to allow the user to provide his own query constraints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't possible with the low-level datastore service. GQL is parsed by the API; the backend does not speak a textual query language.

Why do you want to do this? Letting a user provide a query string is usually a (very) Bad Idea.

Comment: Ahh, was hoping this would be the opposite. It's an internal tool - no risk from bad user. How sure are you about this by the way? 100%?

Comment: @Poni I wrote one of the datastore backends for the SDK, so yes, I'm 100% sure I know how it works. You could use JDO, and allow users to supply JDO query strings, though.